# Bootstrap Grid doesn't start at the beginning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

after successfully working with the Bootstrap grid layout in the past I am atm running into a wall and don't understand what I am doing wrong...

My aim is to create a semi random layout of pictures, meaning that the offset of the imgs can be different from row to rowm but I am careful that in the end it always adds up to 12 so it should start a new row at the beginning, but it doesn't...

Here is the code and the codepen - http://codepen.io/carnivean/pen/yOXjMz:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#einfach"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/61.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#mitbringsel"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/45.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#geburtstagsglueck"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/62.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#girl"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/57.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#fweihnachten"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/60.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#fehlst"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/43.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#glueck"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/42.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#hdl"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/55.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#kopfhoch"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/40.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#muttertag"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/50.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#gutebesserung"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/47.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-5 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#happybirthday"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/41.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#newyear"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/52.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#fostern"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/44.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#christkindl"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/63.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#danke"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/46.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#wiesn"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/59.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#dankeschoen"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/54.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#fweihnachten2"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/51.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#justmarried"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/49.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#essiggurken"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/53.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#valentine"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/48.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#fostern2"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/64.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-5 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#schaffstdas"><img src="http://bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/wolke_du_schaffst_das_17.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#grussvomnikolaus"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/grussvomnikolaus.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#glueckwunsch"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/wolke_HerzlichenGlueckwunsch.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9"> <a href="http://bakari.de/unsere-botschaften/#gutefahrt"><img src="http://www.bakari.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/wolke_guteFahrt.png" class="wolke_s"></a></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see is for example the "Frohe Weihnachten (schlitten)" not at the beginning of the row and I cant figure out why. Any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

i clearly not understand wt u want, but if u want to craete new line after finished 12th-grid so use Clear or Break between two greed.

EX:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>
  </div>

<br/>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```